# VS 2019 WebForms VB-project tableadapter not defined?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webforms, tableadapter, sql-server-2016-express

I am building a web-forms app in VS-2019. I am trying to use code from VS-2017 that worked with the tableadapters in the schema xsd file.  I copied the xsd and xss files into the VS-2019 project.  I can see all of my tables and queries (vs-2019 and vs-2017 both point to the same local Sql-DB).
However, when I copied a bllVehicle.vb code into the APP_Code folder the VB-code looks good but not TWO sentences with squiggly-lines:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports **FCI_Main_TblAdapTableAdapters**     //' <-- **squiggly lines** (not referenced properly)
s
<System.ComponentModel.DataObject()> Public Class bllVehicle
   ' Class variables.
   Private m_i32UID_LOGIN As Int32
   Private _Vehicle_Adapter As **tVehicleTableAdapter** = Nothing  //'**tLOGINSTableAdapter**' <-- has **squiggly** lines
```

It appears that I need to reference the tableadapters but I do not know how.

Can you please help?   Thanks...John D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me but I found out how to reference the tableadapters in VB.Net WebForms in VS-2019.

I had to change the class method to include the **last two missing sentences from the original question**:
I referenced the current project-name.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Imports repo_Management.FCI_Main_TblAdapTableAdapters
Namespace repo_Management
```

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).